# PHP throws JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH on JSON that checks valid on every online validator

Tags: php, json, geojson, php-7

I'm trying to parse a GeoJSON file with PHP and I get the JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH error.

Except - every online linter and validator I've tried is telling me that the file actually is a valid JSON file.

It's a huge file so I can't post it entirely, but it essentially is:

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [
{
   "type": "Feature",
   "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-8.1675,43.3665],[-8.613000000000001,43.3665],[-9.603,44.504999999999995],[-12.078,50.742000000000004],[-11.5335,51.5835],[-11.5335,51.5835],[-11.4345,51.633],[-11.335500000000001,51.633],[-8.118,44.109],[-8.118,43.416],[-8.1675,43.3665]]] },
   "properties": {
      "id": "87",
      "height": "-990",
      "biome": "0"
   }
},
... 2 MB of geodata...
{
   "type": "Feature",
   "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[7.8210000000000015,34.2585],[7.8210000000000015,34.4565],[8.315999999999999,34.6545],[8.3655,34.6545],[8.563500000000001,34.308],[8.019000000000002,34.060500000000005],[7.8705,34.159499999999994],[7.8210000000000015,34.2585]]] },
   "properties": {
      "id": "1493",
      "height": "-990",
      "biome": "11",
      "population": "0"
   }
}
]}
```

Why does PHP disagree with everyone else and how do I fix it (either my JSON or PHP) ?

I made simplified code just for ensuring my code isn't the problem:

```
$cells = json_decode(file_get_contents($argv[1]), true);
echo "error: ".json_last_error_msg()."\n";
print_r($cells);
```

and this bails out on me. I verified that the `file_get_contents()` call does get the correct file data.

I also found out that on extremely simplified data (e.g. just the two features above) the PHP code works. Since all the data is generated from the exact same code, and it loads properly in every GeoJSON tool I have, I don't think there's an invalid data piece hidden somewhere. Can the sheer amount of data be a problem?

Comment: Have you check the encoding? Similar case happened to me in the past because of the file encoding not being utf-8

Comment: yes, the encoding is fine.